# Selenium sometimes cannot locate an element despite having a wait

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Basically the title. Selenium sometimes just decides (maybe every 1 in 10 cases) that it can't find the element and throws me a `timeoutexception` despite doing both a blocking sleep and a proper sleep like

```py
time.sleep(10)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ADD_IMAGE))).click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Please help me.

Comment: please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The obvious answer is that one time in ten, the element _really isn't there_...

Answer (score 0):

In this part of the code, you are waiting for 30 seconds for the element to become clickable, but it takes more than 30 seconds to load the image and make it clickable.

So first check if the element is available on the screen, and then check if it is clickable or not.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import os


service = Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install())
os.chmod(service.path, 755)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
action = ActionChains(driver)

def find(xpath: str, sec: int = 30):
    WebDriverWait(driver, sec).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
    try:
        action.move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)).perform()
    finally:
        return driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)

def click(path: str, sec: int = 30):
        try:
            action.move_to_element(find(path=path, sec=sec)).perform()
        finally:
            find(path=path, sec=sec).click()

ADD_IMAGE = "//*[@id='2']"
click(ADD_IMAGE, 100)
```

This code checks the element available on the screen; if it is available, it will move to that element on the screen and click the element even if the button is disabled.

Provide the second 20–30 times more than it actually takes to load as a buffer.

Even after this, it throws an error, which means the element's xpath might be changed (debug and run the code, inspect the browser when it throws an error), or the element itself might not be present in those screens (handle this scenario using try except).